Relation between volume form and volume of the region created by a closed manifold
In differential topology, we have a theorem states that a smooth manifold $M$ is orientable if and only if $M$ admits a nowhere vanishing volume form. It reminds me that the Klein bottle is an example of a non-orientable smooth manifold. Therefore, there isn't any nowhere vanishing volume form on the Klein bottle. In the other hand, we also know that the Klein bottle has a very remarkable property : it is a closed surface, and it doesn't create any region inside it. This means there will be no internal/interior/inner volume for one to calculate.
So, I want to discuss about this, does the volume form of a closed smooth manifold have any relation to the volume of the internal/interior/inner region created by the manifold ? Thanks.

Suppose $X$ is an orientable $(n+1)$-dimensional manifold with boundary and $M=\partial X$. Let $\vec n$ be the unit outward-pointing normal to $M$, and let $\omega$ be a volume form of $X$. Then the corresponding induced volume form of $M$ is given by
$\boxed{\sigma = \iota_{\vec n}\omega}$,
where $(\iota_{\vec n}\omega)(v_1,\dots,v_n) = \omega(\vec n,v_1,\dots,v_n)$.

may you explain more about the special of that induced volume form on $M$ ?

The intuition is this: If you know the volume $V$ of a parallelepiped with height $h$, then you know that the area of the base is $A=V/h$. Think about taking a small collar around $\partial X$ in $X$.

Since $M=\partial X$ is non-orientable, the volume form $$\sigma(v_1,\dots,v_n)=\omega(\vec n,v_1,\dots,v_n)$$ on $M$ must be zero at somewhere. Let say $\vec n$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are unit exterior normal vector and tangent vectors at $p$, respectively, such that $\sigma(v_1,\dots,v_n)=0$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$ such that $\sigma\big|_U=0$.  Am I wrong ?

The boundary of an orientable manifold with boundary is always orientable.

The Klein bottle certainly does not bound a region in $\Bbb R^3$, by the way. Embedded in $\Bbb R^4$, it is the boundary of a non-orientable $3$-dimensional manifold with boundary.

so, there is a volume form that is vanished at everywhere on a Klein bottle ?

If you remove a circle from the Klein bottle, it becomes a cylinder, so there certainly is a nowhere-zero $2$-form on that. It just will not extend continuously to the closure.
